# how should I understand the sentence I am frustrated to do something

Tags: phrase-meaning

my confusion stems from the sentence structure

```
I  am happy to do something
```

I am not sure but for now I consider this is the same structure as mentioned in the title and in such way I interpret it.

However，there are also sentences in passive voice holding the same pattern (i presume they are the same)like
I was told to do something / the message was spread worldwide to inform everyone.

this is why I want to know how native speakers see this sentence

either

- I feel frustrated about doing something

or

- I am frustrated for the purpose of doing something / for someone to do something

or something other than these two

Comment: Welcome to ELL Stack Exchange! Could you please edit your question to give us a real sentence example? Without any context for your example, we can't give confident answers. For instance, the thing you're doing might be frustrating, or you might be frustrated because you have to do something. With a real context, we would know what you're trying to say. Also, please check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Some adjectives (including past participles) can be followed by to-infinitives. [BBClearnEnglish](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/to-infinitives) explains:

> Sometimes the to-infinitive gives ***a reason*** for the adjective:
>
> - *amazed, delighted, disappointed, glad, happy*, etc.
>
> 1. We were ***happy*** *to come* to the end of our journey.
>    (= We were happy because we had come to the end of our journey.)
> 2. John was ***surprised** to see* me.
>    (= He was surprised because he saw me.)

So your sentence

> I am frustrated to do something

means *I am frustrated because I have to do something*.

Comment: so I guess it all depends on the meaning despite having the same grammatical shape. Thank you for the answer.